# Return any object in Realm that can be deleted

Tags: swift, realm

I want to create a method that deletes any given Realm objects. This is what my function would look like:

```
class Test: Object{
    class E: Test{
        func h() -> Results<Object>{
            return LocalFilesManager.realm.objects(E) //error
        }
        func remove(results: Results<Object>){
            try? LocalFilesManager.realm.write {
                LocalFilesManager.realm.delete(results)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Results<Test.E>' to return type 'Results<Object>'
```

What can't it return the objects? It is a subclass. Thanks.

Comment: What does this mean LocalFilesManager.realm.objects(E), why are you passing class here. What is E ?

Comment: Probably something like `E.self` or whatever it is in Swift.

Comment: @Sandeep E is the subclass of Test, which is a subclass of Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Results` is a generic homogenous collection and generic types are invariant in Swift, meaning that `Results<Object>` has no type-relation to `Results<E>` even if `E` is a subclass of `Object`. Due to these restrictions, `Results` can only hold objects from a single `Object` subclass and a `Results<Object>` collection cannot be created, since you cannot store pure `Object` objects in Realm.

You can solve your issue by simply changing the return type of your function to `Results<E>`.

```
func h() -> Results<E>{
    return LocalFilesManager.realm.objects(E.self)
}
```

You will have the same problem with your remove function as well.

```
func remove(results: Results<E>){
    try? realm.write {
        LocalFilesManager.realm.delete(results)
    }
}
```

However, since you'll most probably have quite a few Realm Object model classes, I'd suggest changing both of your methods to be generic functions that you can use on any `Object` subclass. These generic implementations can be found below:

```
func getAllObjects<T:Object>(of type:T.Type) -> Results<T>{
    return LocalFilesManager.realm.objects(T.self)
}

func remove<T:Object>(results: Results<T>){
    try? realm.write {
        LocalFilesManager.realm.delete(results)
    }
}
```